# Is is undefined to access the members of an unpadded struct with a char pointer?

Tags: c++, binary, undefined-behavior

Suppose I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct RGBA
{
    uint8_t R, G, B, A;
} RGBA;
```

The standard guarantees that R, G, B, and A will appear after one another in memory. And, because they are all one-byte values, I don't see any reason for a compiler to add any padding between them.

My question is, does that mean it should effectively be safe to write a function like this, if my intention is to write R, G, B, and A to a binary output stream?

```
void writeRGBA(std::ostream& out, RGBA rgba)
{
    out.write((char*)&rgba, 4);
}
```

Comment: `I don't see any reason` is not really an argument...

Comment: Looks OK to me. I'd make a small tweak: `out.write((char*)&rgba, sizeof (rgba));` because I hate HATE **HATE** magic numbers, though.

Comment: Yes, it is safe, but there is no guarantee of any representation. In other words, you can write it in such a manner, but when read back in a different implementation, you might not have semantically equivalent struct. Also, you really want to use `sizeof`. And in C++ you do not need to typedef a struct.

Comment: @user4581301 - this is was than magic number, it is plain wrong. There should be no expectations that the size of the struct is 4 bytes.

Comment: I would also add a `const` to the `rgba` parameter and use `reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&rgba)`, because C-style casts are evil.

Comment: This will basically work on every implementation but it isn't technically allowed. You would need to `memcpy` your `out` to a `char[sizeof(RGBA)]` and then provide that array to `write`. The compiler is likely to optimize out the `memcpy`, but it is required.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Isn't it ok to read the memory of objects of any type through the eyes of a `const char*`? From `reinterpret_cast`: "_AliasedType is `std::byte` (since C++17), `char`, or `unsigned char`: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes._"

Comment: Instead of guessing that the size of that `struct` is 4, ask the compiler with `sizeof(RGBA)`.

Comment: The standard does not require that there be no padding, so, yes, the behavior is undefined if you assume that there is no padding.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thank you, that is basically what I suspected.
And @SergeyA I should have made this clear originally, but I suppose my real question was whether it would effectively be safe to assume the struct is always unpadded (even though the standard doesn't guarantee it), which is why I explicitly put `4` instead of `sizeof(RGBA)`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It's intended to be allowed but due to a language defect it isn't actually allowed. They neglect to specify that memory representation is actually an array so you can only inspect the first byte. There is a defect report but I can't find it right now. As far as I know it wasn't fixed in C++20. But every compiler I know promises its an array. Though using `memcpy` is always safe for the purpose of inspection and is usually optimized out

Comment: Why not use a std::array?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oh wow. That's nasty. That means that my debugging versions of `memcpy` etc have `UB` since there is no way to implement `memcpy` (wirhout using the implementations version). :-(

Comment: Concerning all the hints about `sizeof`: A file format is often based on a written specification which requires 4 bytes for an RGBA quadruple. If the `sizeof(rgba)` doesn't result in 4 on a specific platform, that would write a broken file. Thus, instead of using `sizeof(rgba)` in the `write()` I rather would use a `static_assert(sizeof(rgba) == 4)` to become noticed as early as possible if this doesn't work as expected on any platform. And a paranoid fix might be to assemble written contents byte for byte instead of relying on compiler impl. details (but that may cause performance impact).

Comment: @TedLyngmo Right, you can't implement your own `memcpy` *portably*. But for the purpose of diagnostics, its fine as long as check that it works on the implementation you are debugging on. You just need to be aware that it isn't "officially" portable.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux True. I'm looking forward to when this miss in the standard is solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

The notion that "I don't see any reason for a compiler to [do something weird]" should be a sound reason for expecting quality compilers to behave sanely.  The Standard makes no attempt to anticipate every possible weird way that a compiler could behave nonsensically when given code that other compilers would process meaningfully.  If e.g. a compiler were to target a CPU where an 8-bit store operation has to be processed as a combination of a 32-bit load, masking and shifting operations, and a 32-bit store, then it might be useful for such a compiler to process a structure like:

```
struct foo { char x,y,z; };
```

by reserving 32 bits each for x, y, and z, so as to allow any of them to be updated without having to use a read/modify/write sequence.  As to whether the benefits of eliminating read/modify/write sequences would outweigh the benefits of storing data more compactly, the Committee wouldn't be able to sensibly weigh such factors without knowing the cost of read/modify/write sequences, or the tasks for which an implementation would be used.

If as programmer's code will need to be usable on platforms where updating individual octets would be much more expensive than updating 32-bit values, then the programmer should be cognizant of the possibility that a compiler for such a platform might add padding between the structure members.  A programmer whose code would only be used on platforms where such padding would offer no benefit, however, shouldn't need to worry about such things.